# How to write a grunt task that gets its settings from another grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

I need to create a task that fetches all the tags in a repository and builds them into individual folders.

I can create a task that gets me all the tag names, but how do i go about taking that information and feeding it into another task/set of tasks that would run in a loop using that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the task where you get the tags, before running the other task, you could [set the task config](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.set) manually.

Something like this:

```js
grunt.config.set('yourOtherTask.dist.options.tags', tags);
grunt.task.run('yourOtherTask');
```